# What bandwidth does internet background "noise" require?

Tags: internet, 3g

I'm planning to install a small server with 3G-based internet connection in my cabin in the mountains. I will install an ssh server and a web server, both on non-standard ports and use dyndns.org to get a public name.

How much traffic can I expect from random sources like port-scanners and probes trying to connect, will it bust my data plan ?

(My server at home sees thousands of login attempts via ssh every day, which sounds like a really bad idea over 3G....)

Comment: You should move your `sshd` to a different port other than the default.

Comment: how many MB do you get a month? How much data is the web server going to use?  A packet can be 1520 bytes, if you immediately drop port scanners and etc. you can get 680 drops per MB worst case.  
Assuming the packets has a payload.

Comment: It turns out my service provider only deals out private IP's to 3G based connections, so there is no sensible way to get an always-on public site with my current telco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Nice thought about that cabin in the mountains system.</sup>
[Port-scans](http://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html) are usually not full sized packets. Keeping the packet-rate high (with small packets) is a good scan intent for performance.

You should invest in a firewall to not even respond to such scans (no RST packets).

A more important questions is -- how popular is your web-server. If your intent is to host things that will be shared to many people, they will cause a lot of 'upload' for your 3G connection. As your public site reference gets known to Internet indexing systems it will be accessed often by automatic systems.

But, maybe this is the intent of your server-in-the-mountains. If so, the ratio of this legitimate access volumes against background accesses (like port-scanning) will probably turn out to make the latter quite insignificant.